# add in loop in multi dimensional array

Tags: php, loops

i am facing a problem 
can some one suggest me

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++) {
  $r2 = 0;
  for ($t = 1; $t <= 2; $t++) {
    echo $r2;
    $r2++
  }
}
```

output is `0101`;

can  i get output `0123` ??? please

if

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
  $r2 = 0;
  for ($t = 1; $t <= 3; $t++) {
    echo $r2;
    $r2++
  }
}
```

output is `010101`;

can output `012345678` ??? please

and if

```
 for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
   $r2 = 0;
   for ($t = 1; $t <= 4; $t++) {
     echo $r2;
     $r2++
   }
 }
```

output is `01010101`;

can output `0123456789101112131415` ??? please
i think you understand

thanks

Comment: None of this question makes any sense at all. Please **clearly state** what you have tried, what the current result is, and what you were expecting.

Comment: i think i finally figured out what the OP was asking, in which case adotout has the correct answer. however this is a great example of how not to ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all of these cases you are initializing $r2=0; in the inner loop. It should be outside the loop.

```
$r2=0;
for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++){
  for($t=1;$t<=2;$t++){
    echo $r2;
    $r2++
  }
}
```

This would produce "1234".

Answer (score 0):

why are you using two nested for loops ?
why not just use one:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=15; $i++) echo $i . " ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$r2 = 10;
for($t = 0; $t <= $r2; $t++){
   echo $r2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh wait.. I get it now, why you have the two nested loops, you want to essentially raise a number to the power of 2 in order to control the number of values output. In that case, what you want is simply this:

```
// this is the variable you need to change to affect the number of values outputed
$n = 2;

// Square $n
$m = $n * $n;

// Loop $m times
for ($i = 0; $i < $m; $i++) {
  echo $i;
}
```